# SpringBoot STOMP over Websocket connecting to a network of ActiveMQ Brokers

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I built a chat client using Spring Boot Websocket and STOMP connecting to a full featured ActiveMQ Broker. I have six instances of my spring boot application running fronted by a load balancer, however, I would like to scale my ActiveMQ single instance to use a network of ActiveMQ Brokers, I was able to configure a network of ActiveMQ Brokers but I cannot figure out how to have my SpringBoot application connect to this network of Brokers, any help would be much appreciated.
Here is a snippet of code that I use to connect to the external single instance broker.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry messageBrokerRegistry)
{
    messageBrokerRegistry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

    if (UseSimpleMessagingBroker)
    {
        // Destination Prefix - Connect to default in-memory broker
        log.warn(
            "NOTE: ***CHAT SERVICE IS CONFIGURED TO USE A SIMPLE EMBEDDED MESSAGING BROKER. IT IS RECOMMENDED TO USE A MESSAGE BROKER CLUSTER LIKE ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ. THIS CAN BE CONFIGURED IN application.properties => UseSimpleMessagingBroker=false");
        messageBrokerRegistry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/", "/queue/");
    } else
    {

        // connect to AMQ
        StompBrokerRelayRegistration broker = messageBrokerRegistry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/");
        broker.setRelayHost(StompBrokerRelayHost);
        broker.setRelayPort(StompBrokerRelayPort);
        broker.setSystemLogin(brokerUser);
        broker.setSystemPasscode(brokerPassword);
        broker.setClientLogin(stompClientUser);
        broker.setClientPasscode(stompClientPassword);
        // broker.setVirtualHost(virtualHost)
    }

}
```

--